# Where can I download a rescue disk for Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, product-key, rescue-disk

Where can I download a rescue disk for Windows 8? I have paid for Windows 8, but I would like to be able to download a Windows 8 repair disk using my product key. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start the Control panel, and click on the System and Security icon (if you use category view - click Recovery in icons view). Then click on Action Center. Scroll down to the Maintenance category and select Recovery. Click on "Create a recovery drive", and follow the prompts.

Comment: Too late now. The computer I am referring to needs a recovery disk already (I have only had it for 2(?) days). I *may* see if the warranty/guarantee covers reinstalling/repairing the OS, but that is a 45min drive to the store I bought it at.

Comment: You can make a repair disk on another computer if you have access to one. Just make sure it's created with the same OS (32 bit or 64 bit)

Comment: OK, I think a friend of mine has a 64-bit Windows 8 computer. I will look into that. Thanks.

Comment: This would be the correct answer... I returned the laptop, though, for several reasons.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to repair your Windows 8 you can use the "reset" option in the start up repair help menu.

If you cannot get into the Desktop try this method to get to the reset/refresh screen manually. I think the article is asking you to hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while hitting power button.

Please read through: [How To Access Advanced Startup Options in Windows 8](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/open-advanced-startup-options-windows-8.htm)

Comment: That won't work if you can not get to the start up repair menu (I can't).

Comment: Consult this link and it should help you reset or refresh your windows 8 ( reset and refresh are two different options, one deletes files another doesnt ) http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-refresh-or-reset-your-windows-8-pc-complete-guide/

Comment: Please don't post two separate answers. You can always [edit] your existing posts to add information.

Comment: I don't think this will work. Maybe I should tell you *why* I need a rescue disk. I installed Fedora 17, and I used `grub` as the bootloader. So... Now when I boot Windows 8, I get an error from Windows Boot Manager, something about missing boot data.

Comment: This worked for me even though the start-up repair menu was not coming up naturally.

Answer (score 1):

A [recovery CD for Windows 8](http://neosmart.net/EasyRE/) designed to find and repair many common problems is available for download from NeoSmart Technologies, in the form of an ISO image.

I realize this question has been answered for some time, but seeing as the accepted answer is actually on how to *create* a Windows 8 recovery CD from a working PC and may not be a valid option for people whose computers aren't working/booting, this is another option that some may find useful.

Full disclosure: I'm part of the team that developed the recovery CD.

Comment: Full Full Disclosure, this costs money.